# Jaspersoft Studio: Is it possible to set default values for some properties, for example for textField?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

When dragging Fields form the Outline into my Report a Textfield is created with some default properties. I dont like some of these properties. i.e. I would expect my textfields to always have the "Blank When NULL" Checkbox checked.

By now I have to mark all my Textfields and set that checkbox manually.
What i would like to do is tweak the default properties that are used to generate the textfield.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Jaspersoft Studio provides the concept of Element Templates, where you can set default settings for each element in the palette. You can have several templates and set a specific active template to set the "active" defaults.

A quick way to achieve what you are asking is to select a textfield in your document (which has been set to "Blank when NULL" property).

1. Right click the element and select Add to Template Set. If you don't have a template, it will ask to create one. A Template Set is a jrxml where Studio stores your defaults.
2. go back to your report and try to create a new textfield, you will see that the new element is a copy of the one defined in your template jrxml.

To change the template, or restore defaults, use the Settings menu on the top right of the designer view, by clicking on Settings> Elements Template.